# Google play filtering based on Density

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an android game(Canvas based) which has extensive set of resources(*i.e. having a single apk with resources for all densities is not feasible*). So I have decided to develop multiple apks.

Have gone through Google resources about multiple apks support and found that Google Play can filter apks based on screen-sizes(small,normal,large,xlarge) with `<supports-screens/>` element. And for filtering screen densities  is available, but recommended not to use it. My question is how can I filter apks based on device density or device size, density in combination?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the support-screens AndroidManifest.xml attribute

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```